# Water at bottom of dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

I’ve got water at the bottom of my d
Frigidaire dishwasher (Model Number LFID2426TF2A). I’ve checked everything that’s easy to get to, but it’s still an issue.

What I think caused it is that we had a bad habit of washing glass jars before recycling them without removing the labels first. We would have gummy paper residue all over the bottom. I think some paper is lodged somewhere hard to get to.

The traps and filters are all fine. The only stuff I found at all were a little bit of gummy paper.

Our dishwasher has an air gap, and the big hose to the disposer is clear and the disposer is empty and working. Sometimes we get a trickle of water coming through and the water in both hoses is warm.

I can pour water in the hose from the air gap to the machine, but I’m able to fill it faster than it drains. I’m not sure if that confirms the clog is in that hose, or if it’s just the speed of the water draining in the machine.

The last symptom is that the water is clear after running the machine and then gets cloudy by the next day. It makes me think the paper is dissolving slowly.

Short of pulling or replacing the hose from the machine to the air gap, and advice on how to clear the clog?

Here’s a picture of the inside. Are there any other steps I should take to look for a clog in the machine?

[image]

Comment: *"I’ve got water at the bottom of my dishwasher"* How much water? All you're showing us is the sump, which should be full of water but isn't, as presumably you've bilged it out. When it empties after a wash, it uses a pump, not gravity. Have you run a cleaner through it recently? [The amount of scale on the element would say 'not in a long time'. The water softener is supposed to help prevent that, so the softener may not be working properly either.] Have you stripped out not just all the filters but the rubber door seals, spray piping etc & cleaned those?

Comment: There is usually some water in the pipes under the dish compartment, from what was in the hose when the pump was turned off. As long as it is below the dish compartment's bottom, this is probably Working As Designed.

Comment: A lot of water. 2” above the bottom. A bucket full. Not normal. Mid cycle when it’s supposed to drain, it’s just a trickle. Really I think it’s paper clogging the hose from the machine to the air gap, but looking for an easier way to clear the clog than removing the hose, but I guess  that’s what I’ll have to do.

Comment: Is the DW pumping *some* water out on the cycle, or none?  Should be able to see and feel in the drain hose.

Comment: Some. Instead of normal flow, it's just a trickle. Both hoses are warm. I was able to remove the hose to the disposer and see it is clear. I haven't removed the other hose yet because it is more involved and I was hoping there may be a way to soften the clog. I guess it is likely any debris would settle low and continue to be a problem, so maybe I just need to remove it. My other fear is that there is some other place in the DW that could be gummed up but is hard to get to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the clog! One YouTube video suggested turning the propeller beneath the trap, and there it was!

First I had to remove this cover
[image]

Then it was hard to see
[image]

But I grabbed a piece of it and here’s what came out
[image]

Back to normal now. It’s a rushing river into the disposer again and dry inside when done.